# inputhidden value not passing to controller

Tags: apex, visualforce, hidden-fields

trying to send the Input hidden value but it not reflecting in the controller. Don't know why the value is not fetching.. what's wrong here...

tried with parameters and actionfunction also but not getting..

VF Page:

```
<script>
function typeValue(){
document.getElementById('{!$Component.theForm}').elements['{!$Component.hiddenField}'].value = 'Suggestions';    
}
</script>

<div class="container">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <apex:form id="theForm">
         <apex:inputHidden value="{!ca.Type}" id="hiddenField"/>
            <apex:pageblock >
                <apex:message />
                <apex:pageblockbuttons location="bottom">
                    <apex:commandbutton action="{!save}" value="Save" onclick="typeValue()" styleClass="inp_button"/>
                </apex:pageblockbuttons>
                ----
            </apex:pageblock >
        </apex:form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
public complaintFormController(){
    ca = new case ();
}

public PageReference save() {
    Try {

         insert ca;
     }Catch(exception e){            
         ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,''+e));
         return null;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution. Here problem with the ID.
updated document.getElementById('theForm.hiddenField').value. then i got.